# Rename column in a view : bug or feature?

Tags: postgresql, view, materialized-views

I made a mistake on the name of a column in a Postgresql 9.4 materialized view.

I looked at the documentation, the syntax is :

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view_name
RENAME COLUMN old_name 
TO new_name;
```

It worked fine.

Then I had the same typo in a **non**-materialized view. I made a copy paste of the request, forgot to remove the key-word `MATERIALIZED` and... it worked!

Weirder, if I try :

```
ALTER VIEW my_view_name
RENAME COLUMN old_name 
TO new_name;
```

It does not work, I get a syntax error!

In other words : it seems that I can only change the column name of a normal view by using the syntax from the materialized view.

Is that a bug or a feature?

**Steps to reproduce :**

1) Create a simple table

```
CREATE TABLE films (
  code        char(5) CONSTRAINT firstkey PRIMARY KEY,
  title       varchar(40) NOT NULL
);
```

2) Create a view as a simple select :

```
CREATE VIEW view_films AS SELECT * FROM films;
```

3) Try to rename a column :

```
ALTER VIEW view_films RENAME COLUMN title TO new_title;
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "COLUMN"

4) Try the same but with the keyword `MATERIALIZED` :

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW view_films RENAME COLUMN title TO new_title;
```

> ALTER TABLE

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure with `MATERIALIZED VIEW` but for a normal view; the view doesn't store any data rather it's just a saved `SELECT` query and upon saying `select * from view_name` it does nothing but running the underlying `SELECT` statement against the target table.

So the `ALTER` statement to change column name should be fired against the table on which the view is created and not on the view; and it should work just fine. Try below:

```
CREATE TABLE films (
  code        char(5) CONSTRAINT firstkey PRIMARY KEY,
  title       varchar(40) NOT NULL
);

CREATE VIEW view_films AS SELECT * FROM films;

ALTER TABLE films RENAME COLUMN title TO new_title;
```

For a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` renaming column will be possible cause, it does store data.

On your comment: you should re-create the view definition after `ALTERING` the table schema. Check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9ebe1/1

Comment: Tested : Modifying the column name from the table has no effect on the result of the view (the column still has the old name).

Comment: See edit in answer; if it helps. In essence, you should re-create your view definition after changing the table schema.

Comment: This being, I have tested the alter materialized view on a non materialized view and it did successfully renamed the column name in the view / its select statement. This is very surprising.